# Changing data attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
<input id='myId' type='button' data-this-page='myPage' />
```

If I want to change `myPage` to something else, I try this:

```
$("#viewer_next_page").data('this-page', 'newPage' );
```

Is this the correct way, because nothing seems to happen.  I am making sure the element id created BEFORE the jQuery call as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way to do it. You'll notice the attribute itself does not change. jQuery manages the `data-*` attributes internally. On page load, all `data-*` attributes are read internally into jQuery. Manipulations from then on via the `.data(...)` method, manipulate the internal object(s). Thus the attribute doesn't appear to change. However, as long as you access the properties in the future like so `var page = $('#...').data('this-page');`, you'll get the correct values in return.

Answer (score 2):

Try `attr`

```
$("#viewer_next_page").attr('data-this-page','newPage');
```

Comment: Data attributes should be accessed and manipulated via the [`.data(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function, not the `.attr(...)` function...

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `.data()` method only takes `data-` attribute values into account *once* - the first time. When you set it however, it sets *actual high-level data* on the DOM element. You can even set complex objects and functions using `.data()`, which you can't with attributes. After that, continue to use the `.data()` method to extract the value and you'll be fine.

If you insist on using an attribute, use the `.attr()` method as mentioned in several other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$("#viewer_next_page").attr('data-this-page', 'newPage' );
```

Comment: Data attributes should be accessed and manipulated via the [`.data(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function, not the `.attr(...)` function...

Comment: Nope, I got many times zilch when used `data("x")="y"`  (the value was preserved from before), and what solved problem was: `attr("data-x")="y"`

Answer (score 1):

It is updated. Your HTML is not re-rendering. If you take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nH9US/

HTML

```
<input id='myId' type='button' data-this-page='myPage' />
```

JS

```
console.log($("#myId").data("this-page"));
$("#myId").data('this-page', 'newPage' );
console.log($("#myId").data("this-page"));
```

You'll see different outputs each time:

myPage

newPage

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#viewer_next_page").attr('data-this-page', 'newPage' );
```

Comment: Data attributes should be accessed and manipulated via the [`.data(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function, not the `.attr(...)` function...